# Ponteiro para struct

Tags: c, ponteiro, struct

Estava estudando ponteiros para `struct`, e vi que tem duas formas de utilizar.
pode ser:

```
(*ponteiro).variavel
```

Ou:

```
ponteiro->variavel
```

Segundo o que li, quando colocamos `*ponteiro.variavel`, por causa da ordem de precedência, ele acaba entendendo assim:

```
*(ponteiro.variavel)
```

Então, ok. Enquanto praticava (fui usando `->`), me deparei com a seguinte situação:

Tenho uma `struct` dentro da outra:

```
typedef struct {
    char nome[100];
    float salario;
} Funcionario;

typedef struct {
    char nome[100];
    unsigned qtdFuncionario;
    Funcionario *vetor;
} Firma;
```

Na hora de acessar o `nome` ou o `salario` do funcionário, eu tive que fazer o seguinte:

```
vetor[firma->qtdFuncionario].nome
```

Se eu coloco:

```
vetor[firma->qtdFuncionario]->nome
```

O compilador não aceita! Mas por que isso funciona? E a ordem de precedência?

Obrigada pela ajuda ;)

Comment: O que você quer dizer com "O Compilador não aceita!" ?

Answer (score 1):

O membro `vetor` faz parte da estrutura `Firma`!

O compilador vai retornar um erro dizendo que `vetor` não foi declarado se você tentar algo como:

```
vetor[firma->qtdFuncionario]->nome   /* ERRO! */
```

Você precisa dizer ao compilador que `vetor` está dentro de `firma`:

```
firma->vetor[firma->qtdFuncionario]->nome  /* OK (?) */
```

**CUIDADO:**

O compilador vai compilar perfeitamente esse código, porém, se o seu intento é armazenar o tamanho de `vetor` em `qtdFuncionario`, o código *ainda* tem um problema!

Algo como:

```
firma->vetor[firma->qtdFuncionario]->nome   /* NÃO! */
```

Acessa um elemento **após** o último elemento de `vetor`, lendo uma posição de memória desconhecida, provavelmete ocasionando em um código de comportamento indefinido.

Acessa o **primeiro** funcionario de `vetor`:

```
firma->vetor[ 0 ]->nome   /* OK! */
```

Acessa o **ultimo** funcionario de `vetor`:

```
firma->vetor[ firma->qtdFuncionario - 1 ]->nome  /* OK! */
```

Exemplo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    char nome[100];
    float salario;
} Funcionario;


typedef struct {
    char nome[100];
    unsigned int qtdFuncionario;
    Funcionario *vetor;
} Firma;

int main( void )
{
    unsigned int i;
    Firma f;

    /* Nome da Firma */
    strcpy( f.nome, "FooBar" );

    /* Quantidade de funcionarios */
    f.qtdFuncionario = 3;

    /* Aloca memoria para 3 funcionarios */
    f.vetor = (Funcionario*) malloc( sizeof(Funcionario) * 3 );

    /* Funcionario #1 */
    strcpy( f.vetor[0].nome, "Fulano" ); 
    f.vetor[0].salario = 1000.00;

    /* Funcionario #2 */
    strcpy( f.vetor[1].nome, "Ciclano" ); 
    f.vetor[1].salario = 1200.00;

    /* Funcionario #3 */
    strcpy( f.vetor[2].nome, "Beltrano" ); 
    f.vetor[2].salario = 1500.00;

    /* Exibe lista de Funcionarios da Firma */
    for( i = 0; i < f.qtdFuncionario; i++ )
    {
        printf("Funcionario #%d:\n", i+1 );
        printf("\tNome: %s\n", f.vetor[i].nome );
        printf("\tSalario: %.2f\n", f.vetor[i].salario );
    }

    /* Libera memoria */
    free(f.vetor);

    return 0;
}
```

Saída:

```
Funcionario #1:
    Nome: Fulano
    Salario: 1000.00
Funcionario #2:
    Nome: Ciclano
    Salario: 1200.00
Funcionario #3:
    Nome: Beltrano
    Salario: 1500.00
```

Answer (score 0):

O tipo de `vetor` é `Funcionario*` e não `Funcionario**`. Logo, para obter um `Funcionario` (e não um `Funcionario*`), você usa `vetor[blablabla]`. Como o resultado disso é um `Funcionario` (e não um `Funcionario*`), para acessar o campo `nome`, você usa `.`

Sendo `vetor` um ponteiro, quando você usa o `[]` em um ponteiro, terá como resultado o tipo do componente do ponteiro (ou seja, `Funcionario`). Como `Funcionario` não é um ponteiro, os membros devem ser acessados com `.` e não com `->`. Se você obtivesse um `Funcionario*`, aí sim usaria `->`, que só é válido para ponteiros.

Quanto à precedência:

- O que está dentro do `[]` é resolvido primeiro, ou seja, o `firma->qtdFuncionario`, que vai resultar em algum número.
- Depois, o `[]` é aplicado ao ponteiro, o que então obtém um elemento cujo endereço será calculado pelo adequadamente pelo código que o compilador introduzir. Observe que o que é obtido é um elemento, e não um ponteiro. Isso resolve a expressão do lado esquerdo do `.` ou `->`.
- Tendo o conteúdo do lado esquerdo do `.` ou `->` sido complemetamente resolvido, então o que está do lado direito pode ser resolvido. Se o que está do lado esquerdo for um ponteiro, usa-se `->`. Em caso contrário, usa-se `.`.

Como você não usou o operador de dereferência (o `*` unário) na expressão, a precedência dele acaba sendo irrelevante. O seu erro está em acreditar que a subexpressão com os `[]` deveria resultar em um ponteiro, o que não é verdade.